# OpenCV 3.0 - Matching contours

Tags: opencv, compare, contour

I was wondering how I would go about comparing contours, and moving it to show the best matched position.

[image]

So what I wish to achieve is for the purple contour to overlay where it matches with the pink one best.
I have used shape matching, it does its job, but does not show me where exactly its finding the best match.
What I am trying to do is to position an object/part of an object in an image so it is aligned with another picture with the same object in it, and from there I will be able to compare the images even more. For more differences.

I have tried looking at Hausdorff distance but couldn't get it working, something like what it does [here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/cg-projects/98/normand/main.html) where it detects and shows the best fit is ideally what I want.

I have looked around quite a bit, but I can't seem to find a working example of it, this method being implemented.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?